# How to test SendEmailResult for SingleEmailMessage

Tags: unit-test, singleemailmessage, send-email

How could I write unit tests for the SendEmailResult. I want to generate erros in to errResult parameter. What are the possible ways of testing this.

```
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        message.setSubject('failed');
        message.setToAddresses(new String[] { UserInfo.GetUserId() });
        message.setHtmlBody('Something');

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] errMessages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> { message };
        **Messaging.SendEmailResult[] errResults = Messaging.sendEmail(errMessages);**
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fun question! I've tried to noodle this a few different ways and show examples of developer-friendly test cases. But I confess: there is the possibility it will be a frustrating job in real orgs:

- in Sandboxes, the `Email Deliverability` setting might mean *NO* emails can ever be sent
- the "breaking mutation" made in the test case may not reflect the actual real world exception

But it's still always good to aspire to meaningful test cases and testable code :-)

We can go all-out and use an interface to allow mock injection etc. Or use `Test.isRunningTest` in the code to pervert the execution. Or just expose some properties for the test to modify, for example:

```
//this property allows the test to mess with the email 
@TestVisible static Messaging.SingleEmailMessage Message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

/**
 * Code under test
 */
static public void sendEmail() {
    message.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
    message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    message.setSubject('dear diary');
    message.setPlainTextBody('he who controls the spice');
    Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.Email>{Message});
}
```

### Negative test case:

- if the code doesn't throw an exception, we hear about it!
- we make some assertion that the exception is the type we want,

```
static testmethod void testEmailFailureThrowsException() {
    //arrange (intended to break email)
    Message.setTemplateId('a01000000000bad');

    try {
        //act
        sendEmail();
        System.assert(false, 'exception expected');

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //assert
        String expectedTypeName = 'System.EmailException';
        String actualTypeName = e.getTypeName();
        System.assertEquals(expectedTypeName, actualTypeName, 'wrong exception type name');
    }
}
```

### Positive test case

- the act is naked (no try-catch), if it fails we'll hear about it!
- using the Limits class allows us to spy on the actual email side effect

```
static testmethod void testEmailSuccessIncursInvocation() {
    //assert before
    Integer expectedLimits = 0;
    Integer actualLimits = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
    System.assertEquals(expectedLimits, actualLimits, 'wrong limits before');

    //act
    sendEmail();

    //assert after
    expectedLimits = 1;
    actualLimits = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
    System.assertEquals(expectedLimits, actualLimits, 'wrong limits after');

}
```